# A quick way to find the nullity of $B^T A$ when one of the matrices is of big size

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&-1&3&0\\
2&1&4&-3
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&3&4&5&6&7\\
3&4&5&6&7&8\\
4&5&6&7&8&9
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I was intended to find the nullity of the matrix $B^T A$, where $B^T$ denotes the transpose of $B$. One method is to compute $B^T A$ and then find the null space of the product. I'm sure it will work, and no subtle trick is involved, but the algebra is really arduous. I was wondering if there is any property that can significantly reduce the amount of computation. Thank you.

**Edit.** I noticed that $A$ has full rank, and I know the rank-nullity theorem. Does it help any?

Comment: If $A$ is of full rank and square, then the nullity of $B^\top A$ will be the same as the nullity of $B^\top$. This is because $x \mapsto Ax$ is an isomorphism from the nullspace of $B^\top A$ to the nullspace of $B^\top$.

Comment: "but the algebra is really arduous." No, not at all. We have $$ B^TA=\begin{pmatrix} 10 &  1 & 26 & -10\cr 13  & 1 & 34 & -12 \cr 16  & 1 & 42 & -14 \cr 19  & 1  & 50  & -16\cr 22  & 1 & 58  & -18\cr 25  & 1  & 66  & -20\end{pmatrix}$$ The rank is $2$, so the nullity is $2$. But indeed, to compute this with $B^T$ is even less arduous.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You found the pattern.

Comment: We can see also from ocular inspection that the rows of B are linear function so they can be written as linear combination of 111111 and 123456. Two vectors spanning the matrix gives rank 2 and the nullity is then 4-2=2

Comment: @TheoBendit This is probably the best way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [Gram Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process and count the number of zero vectors.